# "Babies grow very quickly." In this sentence is "grow" a copula or a lexical verb?

Tags: verbs, copular-verbs

"Grow" is classified as a change-of-state copula but by definition, copulas may be followed by adjective phrases, noun phrases, or adverbial prepositional phrases. "Very quickly" is an intensifier (degree adverb) with an adverb. Does "grow" still fall as a copula or is it a lexical verb?

Comment: The meaning of _grow_ that some might call a 'copula' is the sense of "growing to become" as in _She grew tired_. This is not the sense of _grow_ in _Babies grow quickly._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> The meaning of *grow* that some might call a 'copula' is the sense of "growing to become" as in *She grew tired*. This is not the sense of *grow* in *Babies grow quickly.*